# Python Error- ImportError: cannot import name '_ccallback_c'

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

I am new to python and trying to run this simple program

```
# Check the versions of libraries
# Python version
import sys
print('Python: {}'.format(sys.version))
# scipy
import scipy
print('scipy: {}'.format(scipy.version))
```

And I am getting this error:
[Error Message image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfOLn.png)

Can anybody please help?

Comment: Upgrade/reinstall scipy. Also, I think you want `scipy.__version__`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, it worked for me.